# What scientific problems can be simulated that couldn’t be simulated 10 years ago?

Tags: simulation

What scientific problems can be simulated with computers that couldn’t be simulated 10 years ago?

I’m particularly interested in cutting-edge scientific simulations, which wouldn’t have been possible (due to computational constraints, or lack of knowledge) 10 years ago.

Please provide links to software, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

This report on exascale computing from the DOE might be useful: https://science.energy.gov/~/media/ascr/ascac/pdf/reports/Exascale_subcommittee_report.pdf